# How can I interpolate a string from varaible in a bootstrap label-success with thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf, string-interpolation

I have the following html content:

```
<span th:if="${game.isWon()}" class="label label-success">
        YOU WIN! Game Score: ${game.getGameScore()}.</span>
```

I can't figure out how to interpolate game.getGameScore() and the raw string keeps getting rendered. I'm using thymeleaf with Spring Boot.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `th:text="..."` inside the tag as an attribute - not as content between `<span>` and `</span>`. Also, if your getters are set up correctly, you can just use the field names (e.g. `won` instead of `isWon()`).

Comment: For example: `<span th:if="${game.won}" th:text="'YOU WIN! Game Score: ' + ${game.gameScore} + '.'"></span>` (not tested).

Comment: throws a 500. Please refrain from posting untested code.

Comment: Understood - sorry about that. I posted a tested approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use attributes directly in text (and not in HTML attributes) you have to use [inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) which has its own syntax.  (Note that inlining is on by default in Thymeleaf 3, but you may have to use the attribute `th:inline="text"` on earlier versions).  For example:

```
<span th:if="${game.won}" class="label label-success">
    YOU WIN! Game Score: [[${game.gameScore}]].
</span>
```

The traditional way to do this, is just to add some extra tags:

```
<span th:if="${game.won}" class="label label-success">
    YOU WIN! Game Score: <span th:text="${game.gameScore}" />.
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a game bean, using fields `won` and `gameScore` with related getters:

```java
public class Game {
    
    private boolean won;
    private int gameScore;

    public boolean isWon() {
        return won;
    }

    public void setWon(boolean won) {
        this.won = won;
    }

    public int isGameScore() {
        return gameScore;
    }

    public void setGameScore(int gameScore) {
        this.gameScore = gameScore;
    }
    
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
<span th:if="${game.won}" 
      th:text="'YOU WIN! Game Score: ' + ${game.gameScore} + '.'" 
      class="label label-success">
</span>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<span class="label label-success">YOU WIN! Game Score: 123.</span>
```